# Matlab/Simulink how to phase shift a signal

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, simulink

For the simulation of an electronic circuit, I need three PWM signals with a constant duty cycle of 50 % and a phase shift of 120° but with variable frequency. I didn't find a suitable block in the library, so I tried it myself. The generation of the PWM was not the problem. The solution for the phase shift was adapted from [here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/simrf/ug/variable-phase-shift.html), but I was wondering if there is an easier solution? This significantly reduces simulation speed. Does anybody have an idea?

Many thanks in advance!

[Simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lSgU.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody has a similar problem: My idea with the "variable phase shift" block is way to complicated. Just use the "variable time delay" block

[simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIchU.png)